# Why does the density of states in a solid scale as $\sqrt{E}$?

Tags: energy, solid-state-physics

In three dimensions, the density of states of a free electron is the square root of the energy of the electron. Can somebody explain the relationship between this dependence and the shape/formation of sub-bands in k-space? In other words, how does the shape and quantity of bands always lead to this same dependence across various materials?

Comment: You've answered your own question -- that's the dependence for *free* electrons (i.e., a single band with $E(\vec{k}) \propto k^2$). Real materials have complicated densities of states that depend crucially on the non-universal microscopic details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of states is always uniform in k, because in a box of length L, you have a uniform lattice in k space, and you imagine making the box bigger and bigger. So given $E\propto k^\alpha$, then you ask how much k volume there is in a band of size dE around E. The answer is always proportional to $|k|^{d-1}$ in $d$ dimensions, just from the area of a sphere of radius $|k|$, times the width of the spherical annulus, $d|k|$, which is

$$d|k| = {dE\over(dE/dk)} \propto {dE\over k^{\alpha-1}} \propto {dE\over E^{\alpha-1\over\alpha}}$$

So the density of states is

$$ \rho(E) = E^{(d-\alpha)\over\alpha}$$

which for d=3 and $\alpha=2$, gives $\rho(E)\propto \sqrt E$.

Comment: Does this relationship hold for atypical band k-space shapes like graphene (linear, forming cones in 3d)? In other words, would the DoS for graphene in 3 dimensions scale as $E^2$, since $\alpha=1$?

Comment: @Caedar: Yes. This works for any power law.

Comment: Erm, except that there's no "graphene in 3 dimensions" ... but yes, graphene does have a linear density of states scaling (near the Dirac point), as Ron lays out.

Comment: @wsc:  massless neutrinos are graphene in 3d.

Comment: No, they aren't. Low-energy electrons in graphene are a subset of objects with a linear dispersion - not vice-versa.

Comment: @wsc: The question is only asking about dispersion.

Answer (score 2):

Because the density of states is proportion to the k, while we know for free electrons the energy is $E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$, so $k \propto \sqrt{E}$, therefore, the density states scales of $\sqrt{E}$.

Comment: This is kind of circular. I don't think it's at all physically obvious that DOS scales linear in $k$ (in 3D!), except by knowing that it scales as $\sqrt{E}$ and inverting your reasoning...

Answer (score 1):

The relation  $\rho \sim \sqrt{E}$ is still pretty universal near the bottom of a band becasue for  electrons with low $k$ (large wave-length) lattice details are irrelevant and their dispersion is like that of free electrons, albeit with a renormalized (effective)  mass. See [effective mass theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_%28solid-state_physics%29).

Answer (score 0):

it is some kind of WEYL LAW ..

in a potential well in d-dimension the number of states goes as $ N(E)=AE^{d/2} $ with -d- being the dimension of the lattice